# I try to integration with zooz sdk in ios but it give some error, so please provide me a right solution

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

**I try to integration with zooz sdk in ios but it give some error, so please provide me a right solution.**

**Ignoring File**

> /Users/xyz/Desktop/Zooz.com/ZooZSDK.embeddedframework/ZooZSDK.framework/ZooZSDK,
>   missing required architecture x86_64 in file
>   /Users/xyz/Desktop/Zooz.com/ZooZSDK.embeddedframework/ZooZSDK.framework/ZooZSDK
>   (3 slices) Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZooZ", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in DemoZooZSDKViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ZooZInvoiceItem", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in DemoZooZSDKViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue when following the installation instruction on their Github. Finally, I've downloaded the source code and built using Carthage for all architectures. This allowed me to run on simulator and physical device.